# How to convert D.M.YYYY string to DATETIME?

Tags: sql-server, date

How can i convert string for example 25.6.2014 to DATETIME datatype ?
I tried

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '25.6.2014')
SELECT CAST ('25.6.2012' AS datetime)
```

but it return error

```
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

because it take argument like month.date.year

Thank for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '25.6.2014', 103)
```

for all date time conversion

http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/

at above link all date time conversions are given

Comment: what is wrong with microsofts official documentation ? I find it more readable

Answer (score 2):

Try highlightning [CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(CONVERT_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true) in studio management and press shift F1

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '25.6.2014', 103)
```